# How to pass information from one intent to another

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Using Google Sign in for Account linking , I have read user email.
How do i pass this conversation data to the next intent?

```
app.intent("Get Signin",(conv , params, signin) =>{
    if(signin.status === 'OK'){
        const email = conv.user.email
        conv.ask(`I got your email as ${email}. How would you like to redeem?`)
        conv.ask(new Suggestions(['QR code'],['16 digit code'],['Cancel']))
    }
    else
    {
        conv.close("Please sign in to redeem");
    }
})





app.intent("numcode",(conv,{num, points}) => {
    const mailOptions = {
        from: "abc", 
        to: email, 
        subject: "YAY!", 
        html: `<p>Hello !! <br> You have ${points} in (${num}). </p>`
    }
    transporting.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
        if(err)
        {
          console.log(err);
        }
    })
    conv.ask("You have succesfully finished.");
})
```

I want to send a mail to  the user , so what should be replaced with "to: email" or what should be added to my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to pass it to your next intent. Once your user is signed in via accountlinking the user's email is available via the conv object. You can call `conv.user.email` to retrieve it. When your user triggers your numcode intent, it should fill the to property with the user's email.

In your mail options you can do the following:

```
const mailOptions = {
        from: "abc", 
        to: conv.user.email, 
        subject: "YAY!", 
        html: `<p>Hello !! <br> You have ${points} in (${num}). </p>`
    }
```